# Grails 1.3.9 application high CPU load after some time

Tags: performance, grails, ehcache

A Grails 1.3.9 application, which is deployed with Tomcat 7 gets serious performance issues after it is used by 10 to 20 users concurrently.

CPU load increases dramatically and HTTP responses become very slow.

Second-level EhCache is used with this application.

We discovered that it helps to clear the second level cache using Melody plugin.

I tried many different setting of the EhCache (changing expiry times, using memory cache only...) but high CPU load and severe performance problems still strike after some time.

We suspect that performance issues are somehow related to second-level cache, but we were unable to find out how to resolve the problem.

We'd appreciate any suggestions to resolve this situation. Thanks.

**Edit**:

Memory history from Melody:

[image: Melody memory usage history]

Tomcat 7 JVM arguments:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Xss1G
-Xmx2G
-Xms2G
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-Dstringchararrayaccessor.disabled=true
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat7/endorsed
-Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat7
-Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat7
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp
```

Comment: It sounds like you're running out of memory, please add details about memory usage/limits.

Comment: @doelleri: Thank you. It seems that it is really the case. Stack size seems to be set much too high and max heap size too low.